# Cleartool - List Objects with Their Labels

Tags: label, clearcase, ls, cleartool

I want to list all objects (including files and directories) recursively with labels their have.
When I run the following command, it writes only Rule. It does not write all labels on any object.

> cleartool ls -r -l /view/stable/MYVOB/MyProject

Result  :

> version  /view/stable/MYVOB/Car.java@@/main/3     Rule: element * TO_TEST
>   version  /view/stable/MYVOB/Driver.java@@/main/2     Rule: element * TO_TEST

How can I list the all **labels**?
In addition, listing **modifiers and modification date** will be plus for me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm), using [fmt_ccase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) options to display the associated labels

Windows Syntax:

```
cleartool find . -type f -ele "brtype(mybranch)" -exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%n labels:%l\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Unix Syntax:

```
cleartool find . -type f -ele "brtype(mybranch)" -exec 'cleartool descr -fmt "%n labels:%l\n" "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```

The idea is to described each element found (`$CLEARCASE_PN`) by using the `%l` option of the fmt_ccase directives in order to print labels associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution :

```
cleartool find . -exec 'cleartool descr -fmt "%En@@%Sn|%u|%Fu|%Sd|%l|\n" "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```

Comment: Good feedback, same idea than my answer. +1

Comment: Yeah, I just want to share the fmt format. I wrote it looking your response. Thank you @VonC