# clearcase command to list down all the labels on all the versions of an element

Tags: clearcase

Is there any command in clearcase to list down all the labels on all versions of an element?

Example
If an element of "file1" has two versions ver1 and ver2.
ver1 has labe1
ver2 has labe2

Is there any command that would list both label1 and label2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea, based on the previous question "[command in ClearCase to get list of all labels applied on an element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25118589/6309)", is to find all the versions for a specific element and describe each version:

(Windows syntax)

> `cleartool find -name "yourelement" -exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%n labels:%l\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""`

or (Unix syntax):

`cleartool find -name "yourelement" -exec 'cleartool descr -fmt "%n labels:%l\n" "$CLEARCASE_XPN"'`