# ClearCase command to get latest label of a file?

Tags: clearcase

What is the `ClearCase` `windows` command to get latest label of a latest version file? I found below command at [command in clearcase to get list of all labels applied on an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25118362/command-in-clearcase-to-get-list-of-all-labels-applied-on-an-element) but it lists all latest labels. How to get last label applied instead of all?

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%l" myFile
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get last applied label by processing `cleartool descr` command as mentioned above. Following is the batch file content.

```
@echo off
@cls
setlocal
SET Command='START "" /B /wait cleartool describe -fmt "%%l\n\n" "filename"'

(FOR /F %%a IN (%Command%) DO (
    FOR /F "delims=," %%b in ("%%a") do (
            FOR /F "delims=)" %%c in ("%%b") do (
                FOR /F "delims=(" %%d in ("%%c") do (
                    echo %%d 
                )
            )
    )
)
)
```

Output: LABEL5

Comment: Nice implementation of my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25118589/6309), you will have to process the output of `cleartool descr -fmt "%lN" myFile` in order to display the date for each label and sort by date.

Using `%lN` will print one label per line.

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%lN" myFile | xargs cleartool descr -fmt "%Nd %n" | sort | tail -1
```

Using `%ln` will use a date format easily sortable: (Numeric) Date and time in numeric form — `yyyymmdd.time`.

Comment: @GORa those are commands available for Windows: simply install https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow (gnu on Windows)

Comment: This command won't work. it will attempt to describe the labels as if they were files.

Comment: If (and only if) the mklabel events aren't scrubbed yet (they are "minor" events and not needed to reconstruct the VOB database in a mkreplica or reformat), you could use lshistory -minor on each of the files to get the most recently attached label.

Comment: @BrianCowan I agree. I suspect there is lbtype missing somewhere. I stayed away from lshistory on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for recently applied labels, try using cleartool lshistory -minor... I applied a bunch of labels to test element and got this:

```
> [brian@thishost cvsimport]$ cleartool lshist -min -last 6 co.dll
> --11-24T14:27  brian      make label "LABEL4" on version "co.dll@@/main/2" (LABEL4, LABEL5, LABEL6, LABEL3, LABEL2, ...)
> --11-24T14:26  brian      make label "LABEL5" on version "co.dll@@/main/2" (LABEL4, LABEL5, LABEL6, LABEL3, LABEL2, ...)
> --11-24T14:26  brian      make label "LABEL6" on version "co.dll@@/main/2" (LABEL4, LABEL5, LABEL6, LABEL3, LABEL2, ...)
> --11-24T14:26  brian      make label "LABEL3" on version "co.dll@@/main/2" (LABEL4, LABEL5, LABEL6, LABEL3, LABEL2, ...)
> --11-24T14:26  brian      make label "LABEL2" on version "co.dll@@/main/2" (LABEL4, LABEL5, LABEL6, LABEL3, LABEL2, ...)
> --11-24T14:26  brian      make label "LABEL1" on version "co.dll@@/main/2" (LABEL4, LABEL5, LABEL6, LABEL3, LABEL2, ...)
```

These events only last 2-4 weeks (depending on scrubbing parameters), so be aware that this is a time-limited lookup.